# Weird AngularJS issue : Directive looping with dictionary

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created the following directive :

```
app = angular.module('sapp', [])
.config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}]);

app.directive("word", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            remove : "&",
            word_id : "=",
            keyword : "=",

        },
        template: '<div>[[keyword]] - [[word_id]]' +
            '<i class="icon-remove" ng-click="remove({word_id:word_id})"></i></div>'
    };
});

app.controller("WordListCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.wordlist = JSON.parse('{{wordlist|safe}}');
    //The above just loads a dictionary as {1 : 'apple', 2: 'boy'}
    $scope.removeWord = function(word_id){
        console.log("Removing", word_id);
    };
});
```

The html code which uses this directive is :

```
<word ng-repeat="(word_id, keyword) in wordlist" word_id="word_id" keyword="keyword" remove="removeWord(word_id)"></word>
```

Check the code at : http://jsfiddle.net/YPgBt/10/
I was following the tutorial here : http://www.egghead.io/video/mZGgNPTHc2Q using which I wrote the code.

Even though I am giving the exact same treatment to keyword and word_id. The word_id never gets printed in the template when I do "[[keyword]] - [[word_id]]", word_id is always blank.

I am looping through a dictionary instead of a normal list. When I click on the icon-remove element, console prints "Removing undefined". After doing random things, I saw a very weird behaviour, If I change the ng-click in my directive such that any of the key or the value is keyword.. that is...  ng-click="remove({word_id:keyword})" or  ng-click="remove({keyword:word_id})" or  ng-click="remove({keyword:whatever})" .. It gives me the desired output, meaning that console prints "Removing 1"

What am I doing wrong here? I am very new to AngularJS, please excuse if I am making a naive mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template of the directive, you need to just pass `word_id` into the function `remove()`,

```
<i class="icon-remove" ng-click="remove(word_id)"></i>
```

And in the controller, you can remove the entry with `delete` keyword

```
$scope.removeWord = function (word_id) {
    delete $scope.wordlist[word_id];
    console.log("Removing", word_id);
};
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjVFY/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, it works. Although it works because in the html I have used remove="removeWord(word_id)". Which makes the directive ng-click completely redundant. I was following the egghead tutorial [link](http://www.egghead.io/video/mZGgNPTHc2Q) which suggests that I have to use the {word_id:word_id} notation to pass local scope variable.